# ember.js beginner advice required

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, materialize

I am attempting to learn ember.js to produce a simple-ish web application. I have read around the subject and completed the basic tutorial on emberjs.com . So far, I have managed to create the beginnings of an API using PHP and I have been able to retrieve that data into my fledgling application. So far so good.

As a starter, I wish to retrieve a list of users from the server and populate a select with these values. The select is to sit on the menu bar and the selection from this drives the rest of the data for the application. I have placed the model in models/users.js. The application menu I have defined in templates/application.hbs (not sure if this is considered correct or not).

I am unable to get the users data for the select retrieved from the server unless I visit the users route that I have also setup. How can I ensure that the users data is populated at application initialisation? How would I apply/filter the rest of the application data upon selection from this component - would I need to set a global variable or something?

Additionally, I am using materializecss, which requires $('select').material_select(); to be run in order to render the select input. I have this as:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

in templates/route.js and works fine on initial page load, but upon navigation to another area and back again, the select is not rendered, and from what I have read, I need to call material_select() again, but I can't for the life of me work out where this call should go.

If anyone is willing to take the time to help me better understand things, I will be very grateful.

Cheers

Tim

**Preloading Clarification**

I wish to have a select box on the main menu bar (menu-bar component). The user will use this to select a user. All content in the app will be filtered to the currently selected user. I currently have an API endpoint (/users.php) which returns the required data, but I am only able to get my application to call this when I visit the users route, which obviously I won't be doing when the app loads initially. So I am thinking I need to preload the data somehow, unless there is a better way that I am not aware of?

Comment: Have you looked at [ember-paper](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper) before?!

Comment: Slightly OT, but I have had a look now - I think I prefer the way materializecss does things. Are there reasons why I should choose ember-paper over materializecss?

Comment: @It is pure ember and consistent with ember apps. But for your case, you need to put that code in application route, `beforeModel` hook. But best practice is that you create a component for menu and do everything related to materialize, jquery things there

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work. Are you able to give me some guidance on the other aspects of my post - pre-loading data, filtering data based on selected value etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component for menu and put the component in `application.hbs`

And in component put the materialize stuff like this : (notice to the place)

```
//components/menu-bar.js
didInsertElement(){
  this._super(...arguments);
  Ember.$( document ).ready(function(){
  Ember.$('select').material_select();
});
}
```

And

```
//templates/application.hbs
{{menu-bar}}
{{outlet}}
```

**UPDATE**

Create a service holding current user selection and use it in other places that you want be changed by changing the user selection.

These codes is just for showing that the solution for what you want (changing the other parts of app based on changing the selected user in menu) is services.

```
//services/current-selection.js
...
selectedUser: null,
...
```

and

```
//components/menu-bar.js

currentSelection: Ember.inject.service(),

actions: {
  selectUser(user){
    this.set('currentSelection.selectedUser', user);
  }
}
```

and in another place you want to be notified when selection changed :

```
//components/user-info.js
currentSelection: Ember.inject.service(),
```

and corresponding template

```
//templates/components/user-info.hbs
{{#if currentSelection.selectedUser}}
  <span>Current Username: <strong>{{currentSelection.selectedUser}}</strong></span>
{{/if}}
```

**Update For pre-loading users**
Actually it's not pre-loading

In `menu-bar` component you load a select box and populate it by calling a service to backend. If you put this component in `application.hbs` you could ensure what you want is satisfied.

```
//components/menu-bar.js

store: Ember.inject.store(),
users: Ember.computed(function(){
  return this.get('store').findAll('user');
}),
```

OR

In application route `model` hook you fetch those users and pass to component like `{{menu-bar users=model}}`

And for these two options you can use `users` in `menu-bar` template.

But pay attention to that if the users count is a lot, this is very bad for performance or UX. If your users are a lot it's better to use from a autocomplete component

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work. Are you able to give me some guidance on the other aspects of my post - pre-loading data, filtering data based on selected value etc?

Comment: @TimHill You're welcome. I recommend you follow [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/). It's the best for starting

Comment: I've been pouring over those since beginning, but I've not been able to find anything that relates to preloading days from an API call.

Comment: @TimHill That is over this question scope. Please create another one and describe what is the goal and problem

Comment: @TimHill Ah you're right. Sorry for my mistake. I updated my answer to cover that parts

Comment: That easy huh?! Thank you :) Any chance for pointers on pre-loading of data?

Comment: @TimHill What do you mean from preloading? Do you want to pre-load all users?? If so, that's not good

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! Working now, but slight typo - it should be store: Ember.inject.**service()**,

Comment: @TimHill Cool, you're welcome. Ah yes you're right about typo